# C# How to convert files to memory streams?

Tags: c#, memory, stream, aspose

In my case,  I am studying to convert PDF to BMP and then convert BMP to PDF.

I did consist of files which input and output.
By the way, I would like to make memory streams instead of files but I would like to keep "a.pdf" and "a_bmp.pdf". 
I marked (#). I would like to convert files to memory streams in this part(#). Here is my code.
Could you please advise me how to convert files to memory streams?

```
 Aspose.Pdf.Document pdfDocument = new Aspose.Pdf.Document("a.pdf");

 for (int pageCount = 1; pageCount <= pdfDocument.Pages.Count; pageCount++)
            {
                string f = String.Format("{0:D2}", pageCount);
                using (FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(#"a_" + f + "_out" + ".bmp", FileMode.Create))
                {                     
                    Resolution resolution = new Resolution(100);                                         
                    BmpDevice bmpDevice = new BmpDevice(resolution);                     
                    bmpDevice.Process(pdfDocument.Pages[pageCount], imageStream);                       
                    imageStream.Close();   
                }
                using (Aspose.Imaging.Image image = Aspose.Imaging.Image.Load(#"a_" + f + "_out" + ".bmp"**))
                {
                    Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.BmpOptions Settings = new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.BmpOptions();
                    Settings.BitsPerPixel = 24;

                    image.Save(#"a_" + f + "_out.bmp", Settings);
                }
            }

            Pdf pdf1 = new Pdf();

            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(#"\\", "*_out.bmp"))
            {                   
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] tmpBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(tmpBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

                MemoryStream mystream = new MemoryStream(tmpBytes);
                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(mystream);

                Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Section sec1 = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Section(pdf1);

                sec1.PageInfo.Margin.Top = 0;
                sec1.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = 0;
                sec1.PageInfo.Margin.Left = 0;
                sec1.PageInfo.Margin.Right = 0;
                pdf1.Sections.Add(sec1);   

                Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Image image1 = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Image(sec1);              
                sec1.Paragraphs.Add(image1);
                image1.ImageInfo.ImageFileType = Aspose.Pdf.Generator.ImageFileType.Bmp;            
                image1.ImageInfo.ImageStream = mystream;
                image1.ImageScale = 1;
            }
            pdf1.Save("a_bmp.pdf");
```

Comment: You already do it in your code!?

Comment: why do you want to hold everything into memory ? : ))

Comment: Because of speed. I would like to convert files(extension: only ".bmp" ) to memory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code snippet in order to export image file into memory stream object and add same image into another PDF from stream object.

```
Aspose.Pdf.Document document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(dataDir + @"input.pdf");

var resolution = new Aspose.Pdf.Devices.Resolution(100);
var bmpDevice = new Aspose.Pdf.Devices.BmpDevice(resolution);

// Export image file to stream
MemoryStream bmpStream = new MemoryStream();
bmpDevice.Process(document.Pages[1], bmpStream);


Document doc = new Document();
Page currpage = doc.Pages.Add();
Aspose.Pdf.Image img = new Aspose.Pdf.Image();
img.ImageStream = bmpStream;
img.ImageScale = 1;
currpage.PageInfo.Margin.Top = currpage.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = currpage.PageInfo.Margin.Right = currpage.PageInfo.Margin.Left = 0;
currpage.Paragraphs.Add(img);

doc.Save(dataDir + "output.pdf");
```

Furthermore, you can notice that I did not use Aspose.Pdf.Generator approach in order to implement the required functionality, as old Aspose.Pdf.Generator approach has been deprecated in new version of the API and it is strongly recommended to use new Aspose.Pdf (DOM) model.

*PS: I work as support developer at Aspose.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. I knew the problem from your answer. Last time, I asked my question in here and Aspose. At the same time, thank you so much for your answer in Aspose and stackoverflow.